# How can I set a particular choice of WIN7 Folder Details as default for all New Folders?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, user-folders

Can I set a default in Windows7 Explorer so that any New Folder will start with a particular set of Details (specifically: Name, Size, Date Created, and Date Modified), rather than having to alter the existing default each time?

Although many New Folders open with most of the above, when I copy Windows Media Center files, the new folder always opens including "Date" and "Type", which I have to remove, and without "Date Created" or "Date Modified", which I have to add.

I've checked Similar Questions - none of which seemed to solve my problem exactly.

(Partial progress: I've found *Tools*, via *Alt*, and *View/Group by* but *View Apply to Folders* is greyed out.)

Advice appreciated

Comment: *"...especially as I can't find an often-mentioned Tools menu in Windows7 Explorer."*  Have you tried pressing the `Alt` key on your keyboard to make the menu bar appear?  You should see the `Tools` option once you do that.

Comment: Thanks - yes I did, just before your Comment appeared, but it's still not letting me solve the problem.